# Problems with the .NET Framework version / Reference not recognized

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

I programmed a Class Library and a Windows Forms app
they're in the same Solution together.

I added a reference from the Class Library to the Forms.
But that isn't working. When I try to use the Reference, it's not recognized.

I searched a little and found out that the Net Framework version of the Class and the Forms is not the same.

In the Class is the Version .Net Framework 5.0 available.
In the Forms there is only till .Net Framework 4.7.2 available.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework .

Comment: Can you show the csproj of two projects?

Comment: There's no such thing as `.Net Framework 5.0`. That's .Net 5, evolving from .Net Core 3.1. .Net Framework's last version is `4.8` and there will never be a new version of it. -- Did you have a specific reason to build a WinForms app targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2 and a Library that targets .Net 5? If not, then use the same version for both, to simplify the whole thing.